# How to add custom resource directory to test classpath without copying the files inside?

Tags: sbt

When I run my tests, the contents of my special resources directory `special-resources` are copied to the `target/classes` directory. I have something like this

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "special-resources",
```

But I do not want to copy these resources into the `target` directory, but I want them to be on the classpath of forked java processes (e.g. for testing).

I have tried using

```
unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "special-resources",
```

but the resources are not available.

How can I add a resource directory to the classpath without having to copy the files? Or, alternatively, how can I setup sbt to not copy resources to the target directory?

Comment: How do you fork your java processes?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski just typical `fork:=true`

Comment: What's the exact command you're executing and why don't you want to copy the directory? It's pretty much like fighting with sbt to exclude what you've told sbt to include.

Comment: it's just `test` or `run-main`. Yes, it's fighting `sbt`: we need to mimick another build tool during a transitional phase and it does not copy `resource`s to the `class` folder. In fact, I agree with our legacy tool: it is costly to copy (large) read-only resources.

Answer (score 13):

To have the contents of the `special-resources` directory included in the classpath for tests and `runMain` task, do the following:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Test += baseDirectory.value / "special-resources"

unmanagedClasspath in (Compile, runMain) += baseDirectory.value / "special-resources"
```

Check that the setting is set properly with `show`:

```
> show test:unmanagedClasspath
[info] List(Attributed(C:\dev\sandbox\runtime-assembly\special-resources))
```

With the following Specs2 tests I'm convinced the setup worked fine:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {

  "Hello world" should {
    "find the file on classpath" in {
      val text = io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("hello.txt")).mkString
      text must have size(11)
    }
  }
}
```

`hello.txt` is in the `special-resources` directory with a `hello world` string inside.

```
> ; clean ; test
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 2014-08-06 20:00:02
[info] Updating {file:/C:/dev/sandbox/runtime-assembly/}runtime-assembly...
[info] Resolving org.jacoco#org.jacoco.agent;0.7.1.201405082137 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\dev\sandbox\runtime-assembly\target\scala-2.10\test-classes...
[info] HelloWorldSpec
[info]
[info] Hello world should
[info] + find the file on classpath
[info]
[info] Total for specification HelloWorldSpec
[info] Finished in 17 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
```

And `build.sbt`:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Test += baseDirectory.value / "special-resources"

libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.4" % "test"

fork in Test := true
```

Comment: Unmarking as answer because on closer inspection this is not working. I tried instead with `unmanagedClasspath` but that doesn't go through and add the resources for all the transitive dependencies :-(

Comment: What about the answer now?

Comment: nope, there are two problems: 1. this doesn't work for `run-main`, 2. this only adds the selected `Project`'s `special-resources` folder... it does not do it transitively. e.g. A depends on B, this will not have `B/special-resources`.

Comment: Ad 1. fixed in the answer with the other scope `(Compile, runMain)`. Ad 2. seems tough and have no idea how to do it now. Could you give the 1. a go and see if it improves the situation?

Comment: fixing 1 is useless without 2 :-( (btw, why `runMain` instead of `Runtime` or `run`? I'm perpetually confused what goes into that part of the `in` syntax)

Comment: One possible solution I've been considering is calling out to a function to populate the additions to the classpath and then traversing all the dependent projects like in the question I asked a few days ago. But that was really ugly because `ResolvedProject` and `ProjectRef` are pretty useless. Using `UpdateReport` might actually help too, but again the result type is awkward. `sbt` is the master of obfuscation and abstraction.

Comment: *why runMain instead of Runtime or run* is because of http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html. It's quite easy **once** you learnt it :)

Comment: As to Ad 2. there's the idea of doing the mapping to every project in the build and the rest would be in sbt's hands. That should work. A working solution later, though...

Comment: re: Scopes. I've read that source code and I still don't understand why these settings sometimes work with `Runtime` and other times need the lowercase version. If it would always work with Compile/Runtime/Docs/etc then it'd all make sense to me!

Comment: Compile/Runtime/Docs are configurations while run/runMain are tasks.

Comment: yes, but that still doesn't explain why settings in configurations sometimes works and sometimes it needs to be on the task. I guess maybe tasks don't always inherit settings from their scope (or the setting is not defined on the scope). But it is incredibly annoying to have to work this stuff out because it is not particularly explicit in the documentation.