# What is intellij's build process for play applications

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I want to understand how `IntelliJ` builds a `play` application. It all looks like a black box to me. I could build the default application using the default `Play2Run` configuration. It seems to use a `Build` script. How could I see what `Build` does?

I want to change the build process and copy some files which are not part of the project directory and thus they need to be copied from some other location on the system. I was able to include these files in the workspace using `File->Project Structure` option but that doesn't make these files part of the build process. I am told that I need to copy these file from the external directory as a part of your build process before deploying the application. But I do not know where to look for.

You may refer to my two related questions to understand what I am trying to achieve

[unable to include external files in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299361/unable-to-include-external-files-in-a-project/48301007?noredirect=1#comment83587913_48301007)

[Include external files (not libraries) in a project in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296648/include-external-files-not-libraries-in-a-project-in-intellij/48297036?noredirect=1#comment83586484_48297036)

Comment: Pleaes take a look at these articles: http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158689/how-to-add-custom-resource-directory-to-test-classpath-without-copying-the-files . There are examples how to add external folders in sbt script.

Comment: Thanks. The reference was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. I do not know how `IntelliJ` compiles `play` project but I notice that if the required files are put in the public folder then `IntelliJ` would deploy the files.

1) I created an sbt task in `build.sbt`

```
/* task to Copy files in ../common/css and ../common/javascripts in public/stylesheet/common and public/javascripts/common*/
val copyCommonFilesInPublicKey = taskKey[Int]("Copies files in ../common/css and ../common/javascripts in public/stylesheet/common and public/javascripts/common")

/*
the xcopy command is used to copy all the files and folders [/s] newer than those already copied [/d], including empty folders [/e]. 'common' folder in destination is assumed to be a 
directory [/i] and xcopy will not seek permission to overwrite files [/y]
*/
copyCommonFilesInPublicKey := {
    val copyCSS = Process(Seq("xcopy", "/i", "/s","/y","/d","/e","..\\common\\css", "public\\stylesheets\\common\\")).!<
    println(s"copy CSS returned ${copyCSS}")
    val copyJS = Process(Seq("xcopy", "/i","/s", "/y","/d","/e","..\\common\\javascripts", "public\\javascripts\\common\\")).!<
    println(s"copy JS returned ${copyJS}")
    copyJS
}
```

2) I created a new sbt task in IntelliJ which would use the task created in step 1 `Run -> Edit Configurations -> + (on top left) -> sbt Task`. I named it `move files to public`, gave `copyCommonFilesInPublicKey` in `Tasks`

3) I edited the default `Play2Run` configuration. `Edit Configuration -> select play2Run -> + (on right side this time) -> select Run Another Conguration -> selected moves file to public (created in step 2) -> moved this new configuration above Play2Run built`

Now the common files get moved to public folder and from there I could access them in the code as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/common/css-reset.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/common/common-styles.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/common/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.css")">
```